# How to enqueue and dequeue scripts with Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I want to create checkboxes with Advanced Custom Fields in an admin panel in the Wordpress backend that can enable and disable scripts.

I created a checkbox field, called it `import_animejs` and checked it. Then used [acf/load_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/) to enqueue the script but I am missing something as it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
function acf_checkbox_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('animejs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/animejs/lib/anime.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'acf_checkbox_scripts', 5 );

function load_field_import_animejs( $field ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('animejs');
    return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=import_animejs', 'load_field_import_animejs');
```

I expect the filter to recognise that import_animejs is ticked and enqueue anime.js but it doesn't.

Update: many thanks to Lachlan's answer this works, and just for clarification I completely removed the acf/load_field "load_field_import_animejs" function in the code I posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do an if statement and check if the field is `true`

This can be done by:

```
function acf_checkbox_scripts() {
    if ( get_field( 'import_animejs', 'options' ) ) { // only include 'options' if the acf field is on an acf options page, if not use the post_id of that page
        wp_register_script('animejs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/animejs/lib/anime.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true); 
        wp_enqueue_script('animejs');
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'acf_checkbox_scripts', 5 );
```